How can I pass arguments to a .exe file?
I have to create an app with Spring Boot, Picocli and GraalVM. The idea is that the customer be able to execute a .exe file and write some commands to see the information needed. I created a very simple app to see if it was possible, but even this simple app is not working.
In this simple example the idea is that in the cmd I should be able to do newSimpleCli.exe Nico and it should show: Hola, Nico!!! but as I said, it is not showing that.
If I do:
java -jar newSimpleCli-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Nico

It shows the message.
Why is not working with the .exe and how can I solve it?
I have App.java:
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    HelloCommand command = context.getBean(HelloCommand.class);
    int exitCode = new CommandLine(command).execute(args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }
}

HelloCommand:
@Component
@Command(name = "hello", description = "Saluda a una persona por nombre")
public class HelloCommand implements Runnable {

  private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(HelloCommand.class);

  @Parameters(index = "0", description = "El nombre de la persona a saludar")
  private String name;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    String greetingName = (name != null) ? name : "World";
    LOGGER.info("Hola, " + greetingName + "!");
    System.out.println("Hola, " + greetingName + "!!!");
  }
}

pom:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.csw.customer</groupId>
  <artifactId>newSimpleCli</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
  </parent>

  <name>newSimpleCli</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
      <artifactId>picocli</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.buildtools/native-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
      <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <executable>false</executable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>

MANIFEST.MF:
Main-Class: com.csw.customer.App

application.properties:
logging.level.com.csw.customer=INFO
logging.log-file-name=newSimpleCli


I created the jar: java -jar newSimpleCli-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Nico
Then I create the native-image: mvn -Pnative native:compile
Then in the cmd I do: newSimpleCli.exe Nico 

And I see this error message:
Unmatched argument at index 0: 'Nico'
Usage: hello
Saluda a una persona por nombre


why do you even create an exe to begin with? Did it run as a jar? did you try adding some print statements to check whether your args contains what you think it contains?

Try newSimpleCli.exe hello Nico

Hi @Stultuske, the customer is asking for a .exe, that is while I am creating it. And yes, I did some prints.

@talex Hi, I already did. It shows this error message: Unmatched arguments from index 0: 'hello', 'Nico'
Usage: hello
Saluda a una persona por nombre

Finally I could do it. I was working with this dependency:

info.picocli
picocli
4.7.6

But I needed to work with:

info.picocli
picocli-codegen
4.7.6


That's great! You should write an answer to your question, explaining why picocli-codegen was required (you can just link to the explanation in https://picocli.info/#_graalvm_native_image).

@nicolasbonder It would be good to put your solution in an Answer to your original post, and mark it as the accepted answer. That will make it easier for others with the same problem to find your solution.

@RemkoPopma done! I added the answer. Regards!

Finally I could do it. I was working with this dependency:
 <dependency>
      <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
      <artifactId>picocli-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

But I needed to add:
<dependency>
      <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
      <artifactId>picocli-codegen</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

You can find the explanation about why I needed codegen at: https://picocli.info/#_graalvm_native_image
